# using get_post_meta() In wordpress plugin after form submit

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple wordpress plugin that will take one or two inputs and display a chunk of HTML using a few pieces of meta data from custom posts in Wordpress (within the plugin admin menu).

I have it displaying the HTML output just fine on a new blank page, as well as displaying the input from $_POST when I tested it, although when I try and use get_post_meta() function using my $_post variables within that html output it draws a blank.

I'm using one PHP file, and the code is:

```
<?php 

 if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>
<h1>My Plugin</h1>
<form action="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'myplugin.php'?>" method="post" >
Enter input:<input type="text" name="info" size="30">
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<?php
}
else { 
?>


<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$info = $_POST['info'];
?>

Information based on your input is:<?php echo get_post_meta($info, '_info',     true); ?>
</body>
</html>

<?php } ?>
```

I'm a beginner at PHP and plugin development, so apologies for all the silly mistakes that are sprinkled in their most likely.

From my scouring on SO and other wordpress forums, I've got a hint that I might be taking the output out of the wordpress 'Sandbox' and therefore direct wordpress functions wouldn't work.  So my question would be, what is the best way to generate my chunk of html with dynamic php on a separate blank page that still works with get_post_meta()?

I should mention that the code works correctly if I put it all on the first plugin page with no forms, and just force a few test variables to pull from the DB.

Comment: "Draws a blank" - are you saying it literally draws a blank page? If so, the the first thing you need to do is edit your `wp-config.php` file and turn `WP_DEBUG` to `TRUE`.  Blank pages indicate there is an error, but the error reporting is turned off.  Turning WP_DEBUG to TRUE should cause it to display errors.  Once it does that, then you should post the error(s) you get back here into your question so we can help.

Comment: Error reporting is currently on, although I should have been a bit clearer, it does generate the html on the page, but literally stops at that point where I have the get_post_meta() code, and doesn't finish loading anything past that point.  Pretty much it grabs nothing, but doesn't generate an error necessarily.

Comment: Fair enough.  You need to `var_dump(get_post_meta($info, '_info', TRUE));` - also, the first parameter is supposed to be the post ID (`$post->ID`) - what are the contents of `$info`?

Comment: I was using $info to store the particular post ID that was inputted on the form, and then used it in get_post_meta. It seemed to work when I tested it grabbing a piece of meta info before I started trying to get it to display in the outputted page

Comment: Thank you for the help by the way.  The Var_dump() function would go where in my example code exactly?  I'm assuming it would replace the echo get_post_meta()

Comment: Yes, instead of `echo`.